# face detection with svm and feature extraction using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst

my project topic is "face recognition" with svm and I have to implement it . so there are many ways and specially new tricks and new topics in some articles for feature extraction before using svm . but I really want the easiest implementation with Matlab! I'm beginner and I don't know PCA , LDA ، Gabor (also heard some others) what's your suggestion? what kind of feature extraction should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, try detecting faces using `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

If you have to roll your own, then take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html), showing how to train a classifier to recognize digits using HOG features and SVM.

Note, that the classifier is only one part of the process. You would need to label a lot of faces in the images. You can do that automatically using `vision.CascadeObjectDetector`, or manually, using [the Training Image Labeler App](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html). Then you need to generate a lot of non-face images. Then you need to train a classifier to tell a face from a non-face. Then you need to write a program that would slide a "window" across an image, and classify the region defined by the window as face or non-face.